# ArcGIS Pro count points from multiple features within polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, point-in-polygon

I'm using ArcGIS Pro v2.8.

I've created a Google Maps  map, covering an area of farm land with different fields.
Next, I created separate polygons to cover each field.
I then created an X Y layer, from a data table with latitude and longitude points corresponding to animal movements (as they enter the field, move around, then leave, i.e. their 'path').
Each lat+long data point has a corresponding number, relating to the behaviour observed at that time, of which there are 3 behaviours (assigned values 0,1,2). Sample of table below.

| Latitude | Longitude | Behaviour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 54.366370 | -7.315758 | 0 |
| 54.366220 | -7.315824 | 1 |

etc.......

I want to be able to count the points that fall within the polygon (field), and get a summary table (count) of how many of each 'behaviour' are within the field/polygon. E.g. 200 x 0, 122 x 1, 50 x 2. I was able to do this using "`Summarise within`" from "`Analysis Tools`", by choosing the relevant polygon, then the feature or path to count (X Y Layer), and grouping by "Behaviour", resulting in the table below.

| OBJECTID | Join ID | Behavior | Count of Points | Sum behavior | Percent of point count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 59549 | 0 | 6.33473 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 631989 | 631989 | 67.230011 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 248502 | 745506 | 26.435258 |

That is all great, I can see how many points relate to each behaviour within the polygon for this one feature (animal path).

My query is, how would I do the same, but for multiple paths/features simultaneously within a polygon? Each path has been added as an X Y Layer, but are individual features.

I'd like to get a table similar to the one above, but with results from all features within the polygon.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't merge all the separate XY layers into one layer? Then you could just run Summarize Within on that combined layer.

Comment: I never thought of merging them, I was worried it might scramble the data. All the layers have the same column headings so I guess this could work. I will give this a go and update with results tomorrow. Thanks for the advice.